# How to make background fill entire view?

Tags: swiftui

I have a background with custom color `bg`.

I assigned it to a VStack;

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello :) ")
}
.background(Color("bg"))
```

But the color only fills whatever the VStack is displaying, how do I make it fill up the entire screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the frame of `VStack`:

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello :) ")
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color("bg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ZStack {
    Color("bg").ignoresSafeArea()
    VStack {
        Text("Hello :) ")
    }
}
```

Comment: .edgesIgnoringSafeArea is deprecated. We should now use ignoresSafeArea(_:edges:).
Just in case you would like to know :)

Comment: ha yes, thanks, I'll update my answer.